# OnTabListener in Android not working

Tags: android

I have run into a problem where when I put the name of a fragment, an error occurs as shows:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment1 to Fragment
```

Here is my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setSubtitle("Created By Rohit Nandakumar");
actionBar.setTitle("Currency Converter"); 
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

ActionBar.Tab Frag1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Converter");
ActionBar.Tab Frag2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Currencies");

Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();

Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1));
Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment2));

actionBar.addTab(Frag1);
actionBar.addTab(Frag2);
}
```

Here is my Fragment1 code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
}
```

This is my Fragment 2 code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is the MyTabsListener.java file:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MyTabsListener implements TabListener {

public Fragment fragment;

public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}
The problem occurs right here in the MainActivity.java file:

```
Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
```

The

```
new Fragment1();
```

and the

```
new Fragment2();
```

part of the code is highlighted and it says:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment1 to Fragment
```

What is happening? What am i doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have already asked this question before, but I have gotten no answers that are correct.  I have searched all over the internet trying to find the answer.  Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
```

Try to do:

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
```

You need to create new objects of the Fragment classes that you have created( i.e create objects of classes `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` not the objects of type `Fragment`. )

The way you are doing, you are creating the object of type `Fragment` but initializing it with the types `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. That's why it is giving the error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1)); and
Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment2)); are saying "The constructor MyTabsListener(Fragment1) is undefined" and "The constructor MyTabsListener(Fragment2) is undefined"

Comment: Then you can try to cast `fragment1` and `fragment2` before sending into paramters like: Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener((Fragment)fragment1));
Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener((Fragment)fragment2)); Try it. I haven't tried it but it might work. Obviously the error is due to conflict in what object types you are passing and the object types that you are receiving in the constructor of listener class.

Comment: The thing is that I can only do a constructor.

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please repeat? Did you mean that you can only have one constructor ? Did you try typecasting them as I have mentioned in the comment?

Comment: Great. Then if you wish you can answer your own question. It might help others sometime with the correct answer.